# How to change deployment password of AzureWeb App with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I want to change the deployment password of an existing Azure Web (or Azure Function to be exact, but I think it 's the same) using Powershell.

So in the Azure Portal,

**MyWebApp > resource Explorer Tab > Go > Powershell**

I have found that command :

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction 
     -ResourceGroupName MyGroup 
     -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites
     -ResourceName MyWebApp 
     -Action newpassword 
     -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 
     -Force
```

But where is the password ?
How do I provide it ?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you understand the difference between User (aka deployment) credentials and Site (aka publishing) credentials. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) for details.

The PowerShell command you have in your question refers to **Site** credentials, and is the equivalent of clicking 'Reset Publishing Profile' from the portal. The Site credential is always a randomly generating string, and is not something that you set to your own value. That is why that command does not take any parameters.

Comment: thanks for making things clearer. So if am not wrong, reading your link, the powershell command I found is for reseting Site level credentials. I can deploy with site level (=publish profile credentials) OR user level (=deployment credentials). I can get publish profile credentials with Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile, right ?

Comment: Correct - Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile will fetch the publishing creds for the WebApp...

Comment: Or as an alternative, you can use the low level CmdLet to call the API directly, e.g. `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName MyGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName MyWebApp/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force`